# tomcat 8 throws 400 errors when dealing with get requests

Tags: tomcat, nginx, tomcat8

it seems to be a problem with the curly brackets {} that are used. 
I have tried changing the connector that is in server.xml by adding  `relaxedPathChars='{ | }' relaxedQueryChars='{ | }'`  but hasn't fixed the issue. also added `URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"` to the same connector.

I am unable to change the curly brackets myself as its coming from an external script and i cannot change the url string beforehand, so i am trying to change settings within tomcat to allow {} but no luck so far.

This is all on a nginx web server, if that helps.

Comment: I have this setting working and I can't see anything wrong in your description. What is your Tomcat version? Are you sure you don't have other "forbidden characters" in your URL parameters? My connector setup looks like this : <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="60000"
               relaxedQueryChars='^{}|[]'
               redirectPort="8443" />

Comment: @mjtecka i copied your connector set up but still no luck - i don't know if this helps but the url string is a get request. if i was to say put {} before the query string it encodes the brackets. Just anything after ? it doesn't seem to encode.

Comment: And what exact version of Tomcat do you use? They've changed the behaviour several times recently (eg. they were using system property tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser. requestTargetAllow  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html for a while) so it would be nice to rule out possible version problems.

Comment: i am using version 8.0.32

Comment: Interesting, they only introduced strict rules in 8.0.39, and this even this (now deprecated) system property was put in version 8.0.42 . I guess that relaxedQueryChars was introduced in 8.0.52 in connection with this issue https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62273 but I am not completely sure. Any chance to update your Tomcat?

Comment: looks like an issue with the tomcat version, will see if i can update it. thank you for your help much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome:-) pls, let me know if you will be able to confirm that this is really a version issue.

Comment: @mjtecka - upgraded tomcat to 8.5.30 and still not working is the relaxedquerychars only working for certain versions of tomcat?

Comment: I think it is.. if it is really connected to Tomcat bug 62273 (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62273), new configuration should be available since 8.5.31 (see changelog re 62273 https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html)

Comment: You may try to to set tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser. requestTargetAllow system property in 8.5.30 (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html). It is deprecated in current versions, but it may work in 8.5.12+

Comment: @mjtecka that has worked! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Tomcat are trying to comply with RFC7230 / RFC3986 (limiting which characters can be used in URL). But it causes problems with some older apps and there is now a way how to override those rules. (see discussion here: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62273)

There were some changes of this behaviour in recent versions of Tomcat.

In current versions (8.0.53, 8.5.34, 9.0.12) you can use relaxedPathChars and relaxedQueryChars attributes of Connector in server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="60000" 
          relaxedQueryChars='^{}|[]' 
          redirectPort="8443" />
```

In older versions, this behaviour was set up by *now deprecated(!)* system property tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow  (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html)

Note, that there are some Tomcat versions which implement strict rules, but don't have this option yet.

(I have also seen Tomcat version that was older, but patched - this behaviour was changed to address possible vulnerability - http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-6816)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use curly brackets in a URL

[RFC1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) lists them as being unsafe characters, and says unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL.

You will have to find a way of changing `{` to `%7B` and `}` to `%7D` before passing the request or by design the request will never work.

Comment: You are right about RFC, but there is a way in Tomcat how to get these charcters working (see relaxedQueryChars in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html). Some older application have problems with this (correct) Tomcat implemetnation so they added the option to override it.